# str_replace by 2 array's created by sql

Tags: php, arrays, database, pdo, str-replace

I already know how to use string replace by creating an array manually:
array('value1','value2','value3','value4');

But how do I use str_replace by values from a Database?

- $original_string = (fruit_1+fruit_2+fruit_3);
- table1 database values: fruit_1 fruit_2 fruit_3
- table2 database values: 237 9388 2377

output what i want: (237+9388+2377)

The normal str_replace procedure i already know:
$replaced_string =  str_replace($searchwords, $replacewords, $original_string );

How do i get all the values from the **database** and process them by str_replace?
Can this be done by creating an array or so?

I use PDO to get values from the database.

Thank you!!!

Martijn

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` can take array arguments as well, so you can do this:

```
$original_string = '(fruit_1+fruit_2+fruit_3)';
$find = explode(' ', 'fruit_1 fruit_2 fruit_3');
$replace = explode(' ', '237 9388 2377');

$new_string = str_replace($find, $replace, $original_string);
// gives (237+9388+2377)
```